# Variable scope and name resolution in Python

Tags: python, scope

I think that I fundamentally don't understand how Python does things like variable scope and name resolution. In particular, the fact that the function `broken()` below doesn't work really surprises me. And, though I've fished around the web for awhile looking for a helpful explanation, but I still don't get it. Can anyone explain or link to a good description of how this stuff works in Python, with enough details that it will seem obvious why `broken()` doesn't work after reading the relevant materials?

```
# Why does this code work fine
def okay0():
    def foo():
        L = []
        def bar():
            L.append(5)
        bar()
        return L
    foo()

# and so does this
def okay1():
    def foo():
        def bar():
            L.append(5)
        L = []
        bar()
        return L
    foo()

# but the following code raises an exception?
def broken():
    def foo():
        L = []
        bar()
        return L
    def bar():
        L.append(5)
    foo()

# Example
test_list = [okay0, okay1, broken]
for test_function in test_list:
    try:
        test_function()
    except:
        print("broken")
    else:
        print("okay")
```

Comment: You're trying to access a local from different scope, that is, in the scope of `bar`, `L` does not exists.

Comment: In `broken()`, inside `foo()` `L` is a local variable (since there's an assignment to it, and no `global` declaration).  The only other place than `foo()` that it could possibly be referenced (or even exist) would be a function nested inside `foo()`.

Comment: someone once said that, to really get Python, you have to understand its **namespaces**.  it sounds simple but it’s actually pretty deep advice in this language.  you’re well on the way if you’re asking yourself _this_ type of question!

Comment: Note that **any** language with lexicaly scoping (including Java or C/C++) would act in the same way... So it's not that you don't understand *Python*, you seem to not understand *lexical scoping* in general which is *the* scoping rule of almost all languages since the 70s or something.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta. unnecessarily snarky for an interesting and thought-provoking question.  certainly not a tone the wider Python community would take and it’s better for it.

Comment: Related: [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4518341)

Answer (score 20):

A function defined within another function can access its parent's scope.

In your specific case, `L` is always defined within `foo()`.  On the first two examples, `bar()` is defined within `foo()` as well, so it can access `L` by the rule above (ie, `foo()` is `bar()`'s parent).

However, on `broken()`, `bar()` and `foo()` are siblings.  They know nothing of each others' scopes, so `bar()` cannot see `L`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces):

> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically. At any time during execution, there are at least three nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
> - the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

Now, why does `okay1` work, if `L` is defined textually after `bar()`?

Python does not try to resolve the identifiers until it has to actually run the code (*dynamic binding*, as explained in @Giusti's answer).

When Python gets to execute the function, it sees an identifier `L` and looks for it on the local namespace.  On the cpython implementation, it is an actual dictionary, so it looks on a dictionary for a key named `L`.

If it does not find it, it checks on the *scopes of any enclosing functions*, ie the other dictionaries representing the local namespaces of the enclosing functions.

Note that, even if `L` is *defined* after `bar()`, when `bar()` is *called*, `L` has already been defined.  So, when `bar()` is executed, `L` already exists on the local namespace of `foo()`, which is searched when Python does not see `L` within `bar()`.

Supporting piece of the documentation:

> A namespace is a mapping from names to objects. Most namespaces are currently implemented as Python dictionaries, but that’s normally not noticeable in any way (except for performance), and it may change in the future.
>
> (...)
>
> The local namespace for a function is created when the function is called, and deleted when the function returns or raises an exception that is not handled within the function. (Actually, forgetting would be a better way to describe what actually happens.) Of course, recursive invocations each have their own local namespace.
>
> A scope is a textual region of a Python program where a namespace is directly accessible. “Directly accessible” here means that an unqualified reference to a name attempts to find the name in the namespace.

Comment: The key here is *defined*, which you should contrast with *called / executed* to really answer the OP question.

Comment: @Calimo, I noticed my answer was incomplete without explaining why `okay1` works, and added some text for that.  In that, I incorporated your suggestion, let me know what you think of it.  The answer may have now become a bit too long, but I don't think I can shorten it much more

Answer (score 6):

It is simpler than it looks.

The first case is probably the most obvious:

```
 def okay0():
    def foo():
        L = []
        def bar():
            L.append(5)
        bar()
        return L
    foo()
```

Here all you have are the regular scope rules. `L` and `bar` belong to the same scope, and `L` is declared first. So `bar()` can access `L`.

The second sample is also similar:

```
def okay1():
    def foo():
        def bar():
            L.append(5)
        L = []
        bar()
        return L
    foo()
```

Here both `L` and `bar()` belong to the same scope. They are local to `foo()`. It may look different because Python uses dynamic binding. That is, the resolution of the name `L` in `foo()` is only resolved when the function is called. By that time, Python already knows that `L` is a local variable to the same function that contains `foo()`, so the acess is valid.

However, while  Python has dynamic binding, it does **not** have dynamic scope, so this will fail:

```
def broken():
    def foo():
        L = []
        bar()
        return L
    def bar():
        L.append(5)
    foo()
```

Here, there are two variables named `L`. One is local to `foo()` and another is local to `bar()`. Since these functions are not nested and Python does not have dynamic scope, they are two different variables. Because `bar()` does not use `L` in an assignment, you get an exception.

Comment: my answer didn't cover why `okay1` worked, so I added a section on it, partially based on your answer and on @Calimo's comment.  Hope you're good with it.

Answer (score 2):

The broken() function throws the following error:

```
NameError: name 'L' is not defined
```

It's because L is defined within foo() and is local to that function. When you try to reference it in some other function such as bar(), it's not going to be defined.

```
def broken():
    def foo():
        L = []
        bar()
        return L
    def bar():
        L.append(5)
    foo()
```

Basically, if you declare a variable within a function, it's going to be local to that function....

Answer (score 1):

The line with `L = ...` in `fixed` declares `L` in `fixed`'s scope. (The `return` before it makes sure the assignment isn't actually executed, just used for scope determination.) The line with `nonlocal L` declares that `L` inside `foo` refers to an outer scope's `L`, in this case, `fixed`'s. Otherwise, since an assignment to `L` exists inside `foo`, it would refer to an `L` variable inside `foo`.

Basically:

- An assignment to a variable makes it scoped to the enclosing function.
- A `nonlocal` or `global` declaration overrides the scope, instead using the (innermost? outermost?) scope with the variable declared or the global scope, respectively.

```py
def fixed():
    def foo():
        nonlocal L  # Added
        L = []
        bar()
        return L
    def bar():
        L.append(5)
    foo()
    return  # Added
    L = ...  # Added
```

Comment: Can you declare a variable without assigning to it?

Comment: @Bergi Not AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The most important concept you want to know is `environment evaluation model`, which is simple but powerful.

Let me offer you a good [material](https://github.com/xxleyi/learning_list/issues/10#issuecomment-468095099).

If you want to read Python document, you can read [4. Execution model — Python 3.7.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names), it is very terse.

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
>   enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is
>   called the block’s **environment**.